# Why do I need content between div tags for the style to applied?

Tags: css, xhtml

I have the code below and noticed that if I don't plug in any copy between the tags e.g. `<div id="header"></div` the style doesn't apply.

- Is it a requirement that there MUST be always content between the tags?
- Is there a better way to achieve the result especially when there is no content to be displayed?

An example of the output can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/7mZxG/

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />
    <meta name="robot" content="noindex, nofollow" />

    <title>XHTML/CSS</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="" />

    <style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #header {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
    }

    #footer {
        background-color: #666666;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">123</div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">It&#39;s a test</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have any content in the div tag, its height will be zero. The style still applies, but you don't see that.

Comment: Does that mean if I applied a `height` property it would appear?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Yes, then you would see the element, and that the background style has been applied. You can use the `min-height` style to set a height for when the element doesn't have any content, and it would use the height of the content when it's higher than that.

Comment: @Guffa - Why use `min-height` when I can use `height` and declare a value larger than what I expect the content to be?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: That of course depends on your needs. If `height` works for all your content, then you can use it. Using `min-height` would work better if you have content that can vary in height, for example break into two lines. If you use `height`, you might want to set `line-height` to the same value to get a more consistent vertical positioning across browsers.

Comment: @Guffa - What do you mean by "break into two lines"?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: If you have text that is longer than the element is wide, it would break into two or more lines.

Answer (score 4):

Divs on their own have a height of 0 and a width of 100%.

Try, for example:

```
#header {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 100px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no content in the div, its height will be zero and you will not see it. Specify a height in your style and it'll be fine.